# How to create form in Drupal 7 with save data in admin panel and export data in excel?

Tags: php, drupal

I need your help. How to create form in Drupal 7 with save data in admin panel and export data in excel? 
1) The first step: When users click to button, form data send in admin panel saved and send email manager.
2) The second step: The manager can export data in excel, view tables. Maybe have the ready module? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not good old webform module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

It provides easy to understand interface for creating/editing webforms, it stores results, can send notification emails, can export results in Excel and other popular formats. Basically everything you need in one module, stable and widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Excel data export](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/jucedogi/2597205) and build your features onto it if you understand how to [create Drupal modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules). Also, consider these libraries [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries), [PHP Export Data](https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it), and produce all sorts of output formats (CSV, XLS, XML, JSON, etc).

Have a look at the [Simple Table of States](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states) example, and think of it as the equivalent of your "data to be saveds". And note the hyperlinks in the upper right, which are:

- [CSV](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.csv).
- [XLS](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.xls).
- [HTML](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.html).
- [XML](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.xml).

Try any of these links to get the equivalent of the extracted information, but in the format you requested (there or other supported formats such as PDF, DOC, JSON, etc).

Checkout Forena's [Community Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2041363) for (way) more details, and/or the [documentation that comes with the module](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help).